# How to prevent WebStorm from opening a new Tab on rerun?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Each time I restart a `Run/Debug Configuration`, WebStorm opens a new Tab in Chrome, which is extremely annoying. Instead it should rerun the same configuration and use the same tab.

The [WebStorm-debug-config documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-npm.html) says, that you need to explicitly allow such behavior by setting the `Allow running in parallel` checkbox, which is off in my configuration.

Is there something else I am missing to prevent WebStorm from opening new tabs?

I am using the latest Chrome and Webstorm version on Windows

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and could not find the right settings in Webstorm,
but if this is an option you could install, for example, chrome extension: "Clutter Free - Prevent duplicate tabs". It will prevent Webstorm from opening a new tab with the same URL.

In the Clutter Free settings also check the "Refresh existing tab" this way when you rerun your app, the changes in the code will be shown, but extra tabs will not open.

The solution is far from ideal, but it is better than the annoyance.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this kind of solves the problem. But the new Tab is still opened and then closed afterwards by the tool. While this is better than before, it is still a hack. Therefore I will keep this question open, and hope for a less hacky solution.